# Add trigger on AWS lambda using Serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

Having an existing SQS queue on AWS (using `ARN`), how can I set it as a trigger for a function on `serverless.yml`?

```yaml
service: test-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  stage: dev 
  region: eu-central-1

functions:
  test:
    handler: index.handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one of the most basic use cases for AWS Lambda and Serverless Framework. Just add an `events` key like this:

```
functions:
  test:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:region:XXXXXX:InsertYourExistingQueueHere
```

You can find more detailed examples on Serverless.com's SQS Queues documentation here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs

Additionally, you mentioned in your original post that you created the SQS Queue outside of your `serverless.yaml`. I suggest that you should create your SQS Queue from within your serverless config. There are may benefits to doing so. If you choose to proceed: Serverless.com recommends using `serverless-lift` plugin to create and manage the queue for you (see bottom of doc linked above).